# Latest Records using Hive

Tags: hive

Input Data

```
SNO |   Name  |     Salary  |   HireDate    
------------------------------------------
1   |   A     |     10      |   01-13-2014  
2   |   B     |     20      |   11-15-2014  
3   |   C     |     3       |   05-03-2015  
4   |   D     |     4       |   07-03-2015  
5   |   E     |     5       |   12-03-2015  
6   |   F     |     60      |   25-03-2015  
7   |   G     |     70      |   30-03-2015
```

Final Output Data
I want to get only current month data using hive query

```
SNO  |  Name  |     Salary  |   HireDate    
----------------------------------------
3    |   C    |      3      |   05-03-2015  
4    |   D    |      4      |   07-03-2015  
5    |   E    |      5      |   12-03-2015  
6    |   F    |     60      |   25-03-2015  
7    |   G    |     70      |   30-03-2015
```

Comment: What did you try already and where did you have problems?

Answer (score 1):

Do this in **shell script**:

```
curmon=`date +%m-%Y`
cusdate="01-$curmon";
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e "select * from tablename where HireDate>$cusdate;"
```

`curmon` will store current month and year.

`cusdate` will store 1st day of this month.

`Hive` query will display all the results greater than 1st day of this month.  (Change tablename and column as per your requirements)

Comment: Mark it as answer if it helps you, so that others can identify the correct answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `current_date` and the date time functions in Hive.   This is probably the easiest way:

```
select id.*
from inputdata id
where year(hiredate) = year(current_date()) and
      month(hiredate) = month(current_date());
```

EDIT:

Having just tried this out, `current_date()` is not in at least one implementation of Hive 0.14, despite the documentation.  So, you can try:

```
select id.*
from inputdata id
where year(hiredate) = year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())) and
      month(hiredate) = month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()));
```